# Select only leaf elements when you have nested elements in xml in SQL Server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008-r2

Posting this because I was unable to find an answer. Apologies if it already exists.

Problem: I have XML describing species with a taxonomic hierarchy.  My primary element of interest, a taxon (`<taxoncl>`), is nested down the hierarchy from a taxonomic rank of kingdom to a rank of species, subspecies, or variety at the leaf (bottom) of the hierarchy.  I want to select rank (`<taxonrn>`), scientific name (`<taxonrv>`), and common name (`<common>`) from sub-elements of the primary element, but only for the leaf records.  In other words, I want to select the record for Wood duck (scientific name *Aix sponsa*), but not the records that tell me it's in kingdom Animalia and that it's a bird (Class Aves).

I want to parse the XML in SQL Server 2008R2 so I can append it to a table.

Here is the example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<metadata>
    <idinfo>
        <taxonomy>
            <taxoncl>
                <taxonrn>Kingdom</taxonrn>
                <taxonrv>Animalia</taxonrv>
                <taxoncl>
                    <taxonrn>Phylum</taxonrn>
                    <taxonrv>Chordata</taxonrv>
                    <taxoncl>
                        <taxonrn>Subphylum</taxonrn>
                        <taxonrv>Vertebrata</taxonrv>
                        <taxoncl>
                            <taxonrn>Class</taxonrn>
                            <taxonrv>Aves</taxonrv>
                            <taxoncl>
                                <taxonrn>Order</taxonrn>
                                <taxonrv>Anseriformes</taxonrv>
                                <taxoncl>
                                    <taxonrn>Family</taxonrn>
                                    <taxonrv>Anatidae</taxonrv>
                                    <taxoncl>
                                        <taxonrn>Genus</taxonrn>
                                        <taxonrv>Aix</taxonrv>
                                        <taxoncl>
                                            <taxonrn>Species</taxonrn>
                                            <taxonrv>Aix sponsa</taxonrv>
                                            <common>Wood Duck</common>
                                        </taxoncl>
                                    </taxoncl>
                                    <taxoncl>
                                        <taxonrn>Genus</taxonrn>
                                        <taxonrv>Anas</taxonrv>
                                        <taxoncl>
                                            <taxonrn>Species</taxonrn>
                                            <taxonrv>Anas platyrhynchos</taxonrv>
                                            <common>Mallard</common>
                                        </taxoncl>
                                    </taxoncl>
                                </taxoncl>
                            </taxoncl>
                        </taxoncl>
                    </taxoncl>
                </taxoncl>
            </taxoncl>
        </taxonomy>
    </idinfo>
</metadata>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `nodes()` method of the XML data type in SQL server to get all of the `<taxoncl>` elements.  Then I used the `exist()` method of the XML data type in SQL Server in my `WHERE` clause to filter only for those `<taxoncl>` elements that didn't contain another `<taxoncl>` element.

```
DECLARE @Data XML;
SET @Data = 
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<metadata>
    <idinfo>
        <taxonomy>
            <taxoncl>
                <taxonrn>Kingdom</taxonrn>
                <taxonrv>Animalia</taxonrv>
                <taxoncl>
                    <taxonrn>Phylum</taxonrn>
                    <taxonrv>Chordata</taxonrv>
                    <taxoncl>
                        <taxonrn>Subphylum</taxonrn>
                        <taxonrv>Vertebrata</taxonrv>
                        <taxoncl>
                            <taxonrn>Class</taxonrn>
                            <taxonrv>Aves</taxonrv>
                            <taxoncl>
                                <taxonrn>Order</taxonrn>
                                <taxonrv>Anseriformes</taxonrv>
                                <taxoncl>
                                    <taxonrn>Family</taxonrn>
                                    <taxonrv>Anatidae</taxonrv>
                                    <taxoncl>
                                        <taxonrn>Genus</taxonrn>
                                        <taxonrv>Aix</taxonrv>
                                        <taxoncl>
                                            <taxonrn>Species</taxonrn>
                                            <taxonrv>Aix sponsa</taxonrv>
                                            <common>Wood Duck</common>
                                        </taxoncl>
                                    </taxoncl>
                                    <taxoncl>
                                        <taxonrn>Genus</taxonrn>
                                        <taxonrv>Anas</taxonrv>
                                        <taxoncl>
                                            <taxonrn>Species</taxonrn>
                                            <taxonrv>Anas platyrhynchos</taxonrv>
                                            <common>Mallard</common>
                                        </taxoncl>
                                    </taxoncl>
                                </taxoncl>
                            </taxoncl>
                        </taxoncl>
                    </taxoncl>
                </taxoncl>
            </taxoncl>
        </taxonomy>
    </idinfo>
</metadata>';

SELECT
    TaxonRank = TaxonomyXML.value('(taxonrn)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    SciName = TaxonomyXML.value('(taxonrv)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    CommonName = TaxonomyXML.value('(common)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
FROM
    @Data.nodes('/metadata/idinfo/taxonomy//*/taxoncl') AS XTbl(TaxonomyXML)
WHERE
    TaxonomyXML.exist('(taxoncl)[1]')=0;
```

That returned the following result:

```
TaxonRank   SciName              CommonName
Species     Aix sponsa           Wood Duck
Species     Anas platyrhynchos   Mallard
```